# Redis build failure

Tags: redis, build-error

I'm attempting to build redis on my aws linux server in order to get access to the redis-cli and connect to my redis instance which is also running successfully in aws.

my gcc is:

```
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC)
```

I downloaded the source and started the build:

```
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make distclean      
make
```

It built the dependencies and then gave me this:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -pipe -g3 -O3 -funroll-loops  -c -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -Iinclude -Iinclude -o src/tsd.o src/tsd.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -pipe -g3 -O3 -funroll-loops  -c -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -Iinclude -Iinclude -o src/witness.o src/witness.c
ar crus lib/libjemalloc.a src/jemalloc.o src/arena.o src/background_thread.o src/base.o src/bin.o src/bitmap.o src/ckh.o src/ctl.o src/div.o src/extent.o src/extent_dss.o src/extent_mmap.o src/hash.o src/hooks.o src/large.o src/log.o src/malloc_io.o src/mutex.o src/mutex_pool.o src/nstime.o src/pages.o src/prng.o src/prof.o src/rtree.o src/stats.o src/sz.o src/tcache.o src/ticker.o src/tsd.o src/witness.o
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/redis-stable/deps/jemalloc'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/redis-stable/deps'
    CC adlist.o
    CC quicklist.o
    CC ae.o
    CC anet.o
    CC dict.o
    CC server.o
In file included from server.c:30:0:
server.h:1044:5: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘_Atomic’
     _Atomic unsigned int lruclock; /* Clock for LRU eviction */
     ^
server.c: In function ‘serverLogRaw’:
server.c:1028:31: error: ‘struct redisServer’ has no member named ‘logfile’
     int log_to_stdout = server.logfile[0] == '\0';
                               ^
server.c:1031:23: error: ‘struct redisServer’ has no member named ‘verbosity’
     if (level < server.verbosity) return;
                       ^
server.c:1033:47: error: ‘struct redisServer’ has no member named ‘logfile’
     fp = log_to_stdout ? stdout : fopen(server.logfile,"a");
```

...and a lot more

I assume that I must have done something wrong as this is code that undoubtedly builds for everyone else.  I'm a java developer with little to no c background. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Jay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Appears that gcc >= 4.9 is required to build redis 6x ...

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Solution was to download an older redis version:
wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-5.0.8.tar.gz

Answer (score 4):

Problem here is latest Redis version(`6.0.7`) depends on `_Atomic` which is not supported in older `gcc 4.8.5`.
One can also compile latest Redis code with `clang` if updating gcc version is not possible.

```
$ cd redis-stable
$ CC=clang make
```

Answer (score 1):

i have successed. 
at first i want to install gcc6, but failed again and agin, then i notise that,devtoolset-6 is deprecated. Maybe you should try -7 or -8.

then i use the flow cmd and it worked

```html
yum install -y devtoolset-6-gcc devtoolset-7-gcc-c++
```

so i hope it can also help you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.  The solution I ended up with was to build a new server with CentOS8 and gcc 8.3.1.  This combination built the redis server 6.0.3 with no issues.  Moral: you need to have up to date infra and software in order to properly build new software.

Answer (score 0):

Download older version, seems some issue with 6.0.*
That worked for me on ubunt 14.04 LTS